# File browsing in typo3

Tags: file, typo3

has anybody had any experience using the traditional browser.php and browser_links.php in extension development for a back-end module? I wanted to integrate file browsing but can't seem to connect it to my extension. Any ideas or other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your looking for [Flexforms](http://wiki.typo3.org/Extension_Development,_using_Flexforms)
with the ff you can add fields to a extension and config them with xml. My config for a filebroswer is:

```
...
<template>
  <TCEforms>
    <exclude>1</exclude>
    <label>template</label>
    <config>
      <type>input</type>
      <size>50</size>
      <eval>trim</eval>
      <wizards type="array">
        <_PADDING>2</_PADDING>
        <link type="array">
          <type>popup</type>
          <title>Link</title>
          <icon>link_popup.gif</icon>
          <script>browse_links.php?mode=wizard&amp;act=file</script>
          <params type="array">
            <blindLinkOptions>page,spec</blindLinkOptions>
          </params>
          <JSopenParams>height=300,width=500,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1</JSopenParams>
        </link>
      </wizards>
    </config>
  </TCEforms>
</template>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

TCA:

```
'field_name' => array(
    'exclude' => 0,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:peproducts/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xml:tx_peproducts_domain_model_product.price',
    'config' => array(
    'type' => 'input',
    'size' => 30,
    'eval' => 'trim',
    'wizards' => array(
        '_PADDING' => 2,
        'link' => array(
        'type' => 'popup',
        'title' => 'Link',
        'icon' => 'link_popup.gif',
        'script' => 'browse_links.php?mode=wizard',
        'JSopenParams' => 'height=300,width=500,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1'
        )
    ),
    'softref' => 'typolink[linkList]'
    ),
),
```